# COALESCE return non aggregate exception on LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the matches of a competition of the next gameweek. A gameweek is when a match is played we can have these types of gameweeks: 20, 21, 22, 23. Each gameweek is played into a specific date. Now all the matches have a specific status, I can see if a match of a particular gameweek was played if the status value is 5, instead if is not played can have as status: 1, 2, 3, 4.

**Main Problem and Data structure**

main problem: the gameweek. I want return the next gameweek of the match already played, so suppose I have the following matches:

```
| id | round.id | status | gameweek | date
  1      488        5         1        1/07/2018
  2      488        5         1        1/07/2018
  3      488        5         1        1/07/2018
  4      488        1         2        7/07/2018
  5      488        1         2        7/07/2018
  6      488        1         2        7/07/2018
  7      488        1         3        16/07/2018
  8      488        1         3        16/07/2018
  9      488        1         3        16/07/2018
```

the result should be: 7, 8, 9, my actual query return this correctly, but suppose that all the `matches` have as `status` 5 (so all the `matches` has played), the query will return an empty result.

So I tried to handle this situation for return the last `gameweek` (if all the `matches` of a `round` has all played), but I get:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'y.gameweek'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

This is my query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.round_id, m.datetime,
  CASE m.status
    WHEN 1 THEN 'scheduled'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'postponed'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'canceled'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'playing'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'finished'
  END AS match_status,
  m.gameweek, m.home_team_id, m.home_team_half_time_score, m.home_team_score,
  m.home_extra_time, m.home_penalties, m.away_team_id, m.away_team_half_time_score,
  m.away_team_score, m.away_extra_time, m.away_penalties, m.venue_id,
  m.venue_attendance, m.aggregate_match_id,
  t.name AS home_team_name,
  t_info.shield_link AS home_team_shield,
  t2.name AS away_team_name,
  t2_info.shield_link AS away_team_shield,
  c.name AS competition_name,
  c.id AS competition_id,
  r.name AS round_name
  FROM `match` m
  LEFT JOIN team t ON m.home_team_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN team_info t_info ON t.id = t_info.team_id
  LEFT JOIN team t2 ON m.away_team_id = t2.id
  LEFT JOIN team_info t2_info ON t2.id = t2_info.team_id
  LEFT JOIN competition_rounds r ON m.round_id = r.id
  LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON r.season_id = s.id
  LEFT JOIN competition c ON c.id = s.competition_id
  WHERE 1 AND m.status IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND m.round_id IN (:round_id1) AND m.gameweek = (SELECT COALESCE(y.gameweek, MAX(x.gameweek)) gameweek
  FROM `match` x
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT MIN(gameweek) gameweek
     FROM `match`
    WHERE status < 5
  ) y ON y.gameweek = x.gameweek ) ORDER BY m.datetime DESC LIMIT 10
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

**Additional further details**

in the first part of the query I select only the fields that I want return from the table joined. The selection is made using the main table match where all the matches are stored. I have the the join on the table team and team_info which takes the information of the two teams that play the match.

After this, I join the competition_rounds which get the details of the round, the round is simply an organization of the match, the same for the season, for example:

```
round.name = Regular Season | season.id = 5 season.name = 2017/2018 | id = 5
```

this doesn't really matter in this question but I'm trying to explain all the query activities.

In the where clause I get all the matches which have as status all the status available, that are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (you can find the status description in the query fields selector case). Later I have also a filter that return all the matches that are part of these rounds: 10, 488, 392, 70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the portion of your query causing a problem:

```
m.gameweek = (SELECT COALESCE(y.gameweek, MAX(x.gameweek)) gameweek
              FROM `match` x LEFT JOIN
                   (SELECT MIN(gameweek) gameweek
                    FROM `match`
                    WHERE status < 5
                   ) y
                   ON y.gameweek = x.gameweek
             )
```

The problem is that `y.gameweek` is not aggregated.  You can solve this by adding `GROUP BY y.gameweek`:

```
m.gameweek = (SELECT COALESCE(y.gameweek, MAX(x.gameweek)) gameweek
              FROM `match` x LEFT JOIN
                   (SELECT MIN(gameweek) gameweek
                    FROM `match`
                    WHERE status < 5
                   ) y
                   ON y.gameweek = x.gameweek
              GROUP BY y.gameweek
             )
```

However, a simpler expression is:

```
m.gameweek = (SELECT m2.gameweek
              FROM `match` m2
              ORDER BY (status < 5) DESC,
                       (CASE WHEN status < 5 THEN gameweek END) ASC,
                       gameweek DESC
              LIMIT 1
             )
```

The first key of the `ORDER BY` puts the rows with `status < 5` first.  The second orders these by `gameweek` in ascending order.  So, the result of this is that the first row will be `status < 5` with the minimum value of `gameweek`.

Of none of these exist, then the third key comes into play, and you get the maximum value.

Another version uses conditional aggregation:

```
m.gameweek = (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN m2.status < 5 THEN m2.gameweek END),
                              MAX(m2.gameweek)
                             )
              FROM `match` m2
             )
```

Comment: the error disappered, thanks. But I guess there are some problem with my coalesce? Because now I get an empty result, this is the full query: https://pastebin.com/u9VdfzmX

Comment: The observation above appears incorrect. The parenthesised portion of the query causes no error that I can replicate.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm sorry for this, I have a lot of tables where the record join data, so is difficult to recreate a production environment in a simple question, actually I don't get any error only an empty result, but should return the latest matches

Comment: @jidic . . . You probably need an additional correlation clause.  But your query is so complicated and the structure of the data undescribed that it is hard to suggest anything more.

Comment: Okay, finally I found the problem, I edit your code: `m.gameweek = (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN m.status < 5 THEN m.gameweek END), MAX(m.gameweek))` and now working, really thanks for the help of Gordon and Strawberry